# How to parse json value of text column in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select

I have a column of text type be contain json value.

```
{"summary":"this is a example","url":"stackoverflow.com"}
```

How can I extract '**url**' json field of column in postgres with query?

I used of following query:

```
 SELECT jvalue->>'url' From table;
```

With my query, I get following error.

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
>   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   text ->> unknown Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument
>   type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the `->` operator:

```
SELECT '{"summary":"this is a example","url":"stackoverflow.com"}'::json->'url';
```

Comment: what if i have a json value like, {"summary":"this is a example","uri" : [{"url":"stackoverflow.com"}]}, how to get url

Comment: note that it will display `"stackoverflow.com"` instead of `stackoverflow.com`. So it includes quotation marks

Comment: Use data::json->>'url' if you don't want double quotes around string. [postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: What if the value is a json string: SELECT '"{\"summary\":\"this is a example\",\"url\":\"stackoverflow.com\"}"'

Comment: `data::json->'url'` will print with double quotes. `data::json->>'url'` will print without any quotes.

Comment: The missing sauce I was missing was not `->` but the `::json` part, because it's stored _in a text column_.